# Using stringr to reformat columns

Tags: r, stringr

I'm in the process of creating a series of functions from an API.  I'm looking for help reformatting the API arguments as follows:

- Take example column and create 2 columns.  The first column will take the text between the parenthesis.  In this case it would start with optional.  I want the column to have optional, then a comma with the text that starts with default or defaults.
- Second column is the text that comes after the parenthesis.  This would exclude default if it comes after the parenthesis like in row 1 of the `args_df`

Input `df`

```
args_df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~argument,                                                                                                                                   ~example,
  "response_format", "(optional) Specifies the format in which the requested resource should be returned.  Valid values are XML and JSON.  The default is XML.",
            "round",                               "(optional, defaults to all rounds) Specifies the round number for which draft results are being requested."
  )

output_df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~argument,                          ~required,                                                                                                   ~details,
  "response_format",         "optional, default is XML", "Specifies the format in which the requested resource should be returned.  Valid values are XML and JSON.",
            "round", "optional, defaults to all rounds",                                   "Specifies the round number for which draft results are being requested"
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
args_df %>%
   mutate(required = map_chr(str_extract_all(example, "(?<=\\()[^)]+|default[s]?[^.]+"), toString), 
   details = str_remove_all(example, "\\([^\\)]+\\)\\s*|\\s*\\w+\\s*default.*"))
```